# How to scrape a page with PHP when the URL has GET variables in it?

Tags: php, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I apologize if this has already been answered and I'm just incapable of finding the right search terms. If that's the case just point me in the right direction and I'll close this question.

That said, here's what I'm trying to do. I want to scrape a page using PHP but the URL for the page relies upon a number of GET variables.

I want to do:

```
file_get_contents('http://www.myurl.com/a_data_page?game_number=37');
```

But that doesn't work, it loads the page as though I had passed no variables. How do you load a file from URL and pass GET variables along with the request?

Comment: "doesn't work" doesn't tell us much. PHP blows up? Your server melts down? Or does the other site reject your scraping attempt? PHP couldn't care less what query parameters are (or aren't) in the url.

Comment: @MarcB, I updated with more information. It loads the file as though you had passed no variables whatsoever.

Comment: If you're sure that `fgc` works against remote servers, then they're just stopping you from scraping, plain and simple, by handling you request and delivering only the default index page.

Comment: if that url works in a browser but not php, then you're probably missing something, like a cookie/login that you did in the browser.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, I get the page back, but where the dynamic part is there's just a hole. Does this confirm your suspicion? The site is ghetto enough that I doubt that they are preventing scraping.

Comment: We would have to see the site in question to be able to help.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy this is what I'm trying to scrape: http://www.masslottery.com/games/lottery/search/results-todays.html?game_id=15&mode=2&min=1634190

Comment: And that's because what you actually want is [Located here](http://www.masslottery.com/data/json/search/dailygames/todays/keno.json). Enjoy. :)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy WHERE DID YOU FIND THIS?! I LOVE YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Let me share a secret with you. In chrome, open a new tab, make the url: `chrome://net-internals/#events`, refresh the page that you want, then go back to the tab, Cntrl +f 'json'. You can also use the filter bar and type in `URL REQUEST json` and it will show you all `URL_REQUEST` source types along with strings that have "json" in them, which end points have from time to time.